# Batch - Opening a command prompt, then navigating to the directory and running a command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My folder structure is like this:

```
js:
  folder1:
    subfolder1
    subfolder2
  folder2:
    ...
    ...
  folder3:
    ...
    ...
```

Now I want to create a batch file that sits in the js folder that when executed, navigates inside each folder (folder1, folder2, folder3) and not in their subfolders, open a command prompt and run the command `npm i`.

I have this command

```
for /D %%y in (*) do (
    start cmd /k cd %%y & npm i
)
```

but it just opens up 3 command prompts, so navigating correctly but fails to run the npm command. I'm very new to batch programming so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the options of the `START` command to your advantage. `start "" /D "%%y" cmd /k npm i`

Comment: You change the directory in the inner `cmd.exe` instance, but `npm` is executed in the hosting one; to avoid that replace `&` by `^&`…

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble upon this question, here's the answer with the help of @aschipfl in the comments. The second command was being executed in the host cmd window and not in the new spawned prompts.

```
for /D %%y in (*) do (
    start cmd /k cd %%y & npm run erp-dev
)
```